# Round Table Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have an issue with two problems with round table.
I have $n$ families, each family have father, mother, kid and a dog.
First problem: I need to sit the families that every kid sits between his parents.
Second problem: I need to sit the families that the two parents sit together and no dogs near each other.

In the first problem I tried to stick the parents and the kid together like this:
I have total of $2n$ places in the table, so to sit the parents and kid between them I have $n!$ options (and multiplies by $2$ because the side the parents sit) and $(n-1)!$ for the dogs to sit.

$$n!\cdot 2\cdot (n-1)!$$
but I'm not really sure about it.

And in the second problem I thought to stick the parents together and the kid and the dog together, but it seems to be wrong because I need the dog the be alone because there can be a possibility that the dog can be between two couples of parents.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for editing the Question to include your thoughts.  Grouping the parents and kid together in each family is a good idea.  Do we seat all $n$ families at the same table?

Comment: yes, all n families sit in the same table, without any limitation there are (4n-1)! option. but I failed to do the calculation for 3 objects (parents, kids, and parents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, the factor $2$ applies to each family, so that would give $2^n$.  Presumably the dogs need to go between the families, but dogs can be together so you are ordering $2n$ (families plus dogs).  The result is $2^n(2n-1)!$

For the second, you have $n$ couples, $n$ kids, and $n$ dogs to seat.  You again get a factor $2^n$ for the couples' order.  Then attach a couple or kid to the right of each dog.  You have $2n$ choices for the first dog, $2n-1$ for the second, and so on.  This gives a factor $\frac {(2n)!}{n!}$.  Now you have $2n$ groups to arrange around the circle, which you can do in $(2n-1)!$ ways, for a final result of $2^n\frac {(2n)!(2n-1)!}{n!}$

Comment: Thank you very much!, it was very helpful